# survival package errors R

Tags: r, ubuntu, package

I've been having some problems installing the 'survival' package in R. I have tried almost everything including trying to build from source, and I'm getting this same error.

```
>>install.package('survival')

Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib)
    shared object ‘Matrix.so’ not found
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘survival’
* removing ‘/home/dave/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/survival’
```

my distro--

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: after isntlal 'rcpp' and its dependicies. i'm not getting the Lock error anymore. but still having the above error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix.so is a shared object as part of the Matrix package. So I tried installing that by this--

```
>> install.packages("Matrix")
ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘/home/dave/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’ for modifying    
Try removing ‘/home/dave/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/00LOCK-Matrix’
```

after:
`sudo rm -rf /home/dave/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/00LOCK-Matrix`

Re-enter R shell and did `install.packages('Matrix')` and it was built properly. Then doing `install.packages('survival')` worked.